# SMS message text absurdly large

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, sms, fonts

My LG Optimus Fuel (running factory-installed, non-rooted KitKat) is displaying SMS and MMS message text in the Messaging app at a very large size, as seen below.

[image: Large SMS font]

I have looked through the app's settings and System Settings, to no avail. System text size is set to "Normal", but this problem still occurs, and only in this app.

Any solutions?

Comment: Yes. Every other app works fine.

Comment: There's [a post on AndroidCentral forum](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-4-1-4-2-4-3-jelly-bean/348373-font-size-text-messages-how-change.html) to try the volume button (no additional info on the device/app though, but it doesn't hurt to try)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. I was easily able to fix it by using pinch gestures on the screen. It works the same as viewing a webpage. Pinch apart to zoom in, pinch together to zoom out.

Comment: I was going to say this, you've pinched the screen to zoom in!

Answer (score -2):

You could also just use the volume keys to zoom in/out.